# Identification of store-bought succulent plant

Tags: botany, species-identification

I bought this succulent in the Bronx Botanical Garden Shop, but it was unlabeled. On the photo it is about 4" high:
[image]
Can anyone help identify this? Could this be *Echeveria haagai*? It's indoors in NYC.

Comment: Please provide your location as well as where you obtained the specimen. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason I have any clue as to what this could be is because I have one that looks exactly like it and, in a stroke of sheer genius, I wrote the name on the bottom of the pot. I think it is some member of [x *Pachyveria*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%97_Pachyveria), which are intergeneric hybrids of [*Pachyphytum*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachyphytum) and [*Echeveria*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echeveria). Because there are so many, determining the exact cultivar may prove difficult. Mine is "Blue Pearl" and it looked very similar until it's untimely demise.

You can check out [this website](https://public.fotki.com/Grootscholten/plant-collections/pachyphytum-veria/) to see some different varieties. Actually, some of the *Pachyphytum* look pretty close too.

Compare w/ x *Pachyveria* "Cheyenne" ([source](https://www.flickr.com/photos/92114826@N03/16978978668)):

[image]

and x *Pachyveria* "Little Jewel" ([source](http://www.cactuseros.com/Especie/21615/Pachyveria_glauca_(Pachyphytum_hookeri_x_Echeveria_sp.)_(HIBRIDO).html)):

[image]